# Loading icon becomes status icon after controller function AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**How can I change a icon in my view during the execution in a controller function ?**
At the beginning of my function the icon should be a turning wheel to show that the status is loading and working at the moment.
[image: function is working]
Then after the execution the status is either true or false. This should be indicated with some kind of icon. Let´s take this example for simplicity:
Status true: [image]
Status false:[image]

I tried to change the attributes with `ng-bind-html="statusIcon"` in my template
and `$scope.statusIcon = <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>` in my controller which caused an `insecure-error`.

Maybe you guys can help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Could you put up a plunkr to speed up the process of helping you out?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use ng-show and ng-hide to conditionally show one image or the other:

html:

```
  <p>Status: 
    <span ng-show="loading"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i></span>
    <span ng-hide="loading"><i class="fa fa-x-or-whatever-it-is"></i></span>
  </p>
```

controller:

```
  $scope.loading = false;
  function getData() {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $http.get(someUrl).then(function(data) {
      $scope.data = data.data;
      $scope.loading = false;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To safely use `ng-bind-html`, you need to also use [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce).

Fortunately, in this case there's no need to use `ng-bind-html`.  (That's true in general, unless you're handling user input that contains HTML. As much as possible, try to keep your HTML in your templates, not in your controllers.)

In your controller: `$scope.statusIcon = "check";`

In your template:

```
<i class="fa" ng-class="{
    'fa-check-square-o': statusIcon == 'check',
    'fa-spinner':        statusIcon == 'spinner',
    'fa-whatever':       statusIcon == 'etcetera'
}"></i>
```

(Or if you want to be super lazy about it, you could just interpolate the classname itself, a la `<i class="fa {{statusIcon}}">`.)